# I want background-image transition fadein when addclass

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image

If background is color header-fixed-position, color is fadein but if background is image, image is not fadein.

Sorry i'm not good at english, See the sample code below.
Try delete comment background-image in CSS.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
    $('#header').addClass('headtop');
  } else {
    $('#header').removeClass('headtop');
  }
});
```

```css
#header {
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.headtop { 
    z-index: 997; 
    position: fixed; 
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
    /*background-image: url(https://cdn.mmaweekly.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/WME-IMG-750x370-748x370.jpg);*/
    border-radius: 0px 0px 25px 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="header" class="container">
<h1>this is header</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content

</div>
```

Comment: You can't fade a `background-image` from none to an image. Actually, `background-image` does not allow any transition. You could however just fade in the whole element where the background image is defined in. You would then transition the `opacity` property accordingly.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 Is there a way to use opacity in this snippet ?

Comment: If you want the background Img to transition, you'll have to have a previous one, other wise it will just pop up. Check this : https://fiddle.jshell.net/yzpfmt10/ and see how the first img popup but the rest animate.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by adding a div with the background image and using the opacity 0 to 1 transition.

Here is an example with your code:

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
    $('#header').addClass('headtop');
  } else {
    $('#header').removeClass('headtop');
  }
});
```

```css
#header {
    transition: all 1s ease;
}

.headtop { 
    z-index: 997; 
    position: fixed; 
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    top: 0;
    background-color: #aaaaaa;
    
    border-radius: 0px 0px 25px 25px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
    opacity:1 !important;
}

#header .background {
  z-index: -1;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height: 69px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 25px 25px;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.mmaweekly.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/WME-IMG-750x370-748x370.jpg);
  top: 0;
  opacity:0;
}

.headtop .background {
  opacity:1 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <div class="background"></div>
  <h1>this is header</h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content<br>this is  content

</div>
```